# Error in javascript reduce method using typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am learning Typescript by building a node application. I am using MySQL via sequelize for the database. I want to use `.reduce()` method in one of the results I got from the database.

Here is my code:

```
 const orderedInstances = await createOrderedItemClass.findAll({where: {cartId: 
 cart.dataValues.id}});

 orderedInstances.reduce((prev, current)=>{
        
        return prev.dataValues.food_total_sum as number + current.dataValues.food_total_sum as 
   number
   },)
```

Here is my error from `typescript`:

```
 Argument of type '(prev: createOrderedItemClass, current: createOrderedItemClass) => number' 
is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: createOrderedItemClass, currentValue: 
createOrderedItemClass, currentIndex: number, array: createOrderedItemClass[]) => 
createOrderedItemClass'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'createOrderedItemClass'.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: sum up the numbers in those values. I know I can do this with map method or for loop method too. But I am just curious how can I use reduce method here as typescript is telling me of a type error.

Comment: @kingsJayson _"I know I can do this with map method..."_ - No, `.map()` is definitely the wrong tool for this...

Comment: You're missing an initial value for reduce. If you don't pass an initial value, the first element in the array is used instead.

Comment: Don't wrap words in code tags that are not actual code.

Comment: Your `.reduce()` callback returns a number but you treat it like an object.

Comment: @Andreas.... well, maybe it is the wrong tool but gave me what I wanted. I have data in an array with objects. This data is coming from Sequelize. The value I am targetting from each of the object is a number and I want to sum them up. Map simply did that for me with a let variable which has a 0 value and I simply updated the let value on each iteration using addition assignment ( += ) . It summed up the values coming from dataValues.food_total_sum

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not meant to just iterate over a collection. That's what [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is for. `.map()`: _"The `map()` method **creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function** on every element in the calling array. "_

Comment: Like I said, maybe it is the wrong tool. But it gave me what I wanted. For now, I am interested in seeing how the reduce() will do same for me,

Answer (score 0):

Reduce works differently. It is not prev and current value, but more like accumulator and current value.
So, the result of iteration is stored in the first argument which in your case is 'prev'. The result of iteration is a number. And you try to access dataValues.food_total_sum in a number which is an error.

Try like this:

```
const orderedInstances = await createOrderedItemClass.findAll({where: {cartId: 
 cart.dataValues.id}});

 orderedInstances.reduce((prev, current)=>{
        
        return prev + current.dataValues.food_total_sum as 
   number
   }, 0)
```